# smarty bundle installation and assetic.use_controller

Tags: symfony, smarty3, symfony-2.3

I'm using Symfony version 2.3.1 and SmartyBundle version 1.2.0.

I followed the steps 2.3 and 2.4 at https://smartybundle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html.

But as soon as I enable SmartyBundle in AppKernel.php, I have this error in app/console:

```
You have requested a non-existent parameter "assetic.use_controller".
```

Here is an excerpt of my config.yml:

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
```

Comment: Do you have AsseticBundle in your application? ... registered in the AppKernel ?

Comment: @nifr Thanks for the pointer! I'm new at Symphony2, and it seems that in registerBundles I had to add the SmartyBundle after AsseticBundle (I had added it right after TwigBundle and got the same problem as Alsciende).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.

You need to make sure that the SmartyBundle appears after AsseticBundle in AppKernel registerBundles